# How do I make a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a nested dictionary as my following outputs is: `{'bulbasaur': ['grass', 'South America']`
Although I desire to get the following `{'bulbasaur': {'grass', 'South America'}`

```
def read_pokedata(filename):
    file= open(filename, "r")
    results= {}
    for i in file:
        strip= i.strip().split(",")
        value=strip[0]
        results[value[0:]]=strip[1:]
    return results
print(read_pokedata("pokemonLocations.txt"))
```

Comment: try using the python builtin json module with json.loads

Comment: That's a set, not a dictionary inside

Comment: What's your actual input? I have no idea what your file looks like.

Comment: The desired output you provided is not a nested dictionary, that is a dictionary item with a `set()` as the value. A nested dictionary would look like `{'bulbasaur': {'type': 'grass', 'location': 'South America'}}`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

A simple explicit typecasting from list to set should work.

```
results[value[0:]]=set(strip[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that what you are really after is this result:

```
{'bulbasaur': {'grass': 'South America'}}
```

In that case it's a simple iteration.

```
a={'bulbasaur': ['grass', 'South America']}
b={k:{li[0]:li[1]} for k,li in a.items()}
print(b)
```